# Cannot access pages that are not in the root dir

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am getting an error when clicking on a link to access a page. I have 2 href links. These look like this

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="../pages/addUser">New member</a>
</li>
```

My router `(called memberRoutes.js)` looks like this:

```
    const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    member = require('../controllers/members')
    
    router.get('/', member.addUser);

module.exports = router;
```

And my controller `(called member.js)` looks like this:

```
exports.addUser = ('/addUser', (req, res) => {        
    res.render('../views/pages/addUser');
});
```

I have also tried just having `exports.addUser = ('/', (req, res) => {...`

When I click on the `<a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>` it works fine. But I also want to be able to click on another link that takes me to some other page.

I have also tried having it as: `<a class="nav-link" href="/addUser">New member</a>`

The following code/link below gives me an error, saying : `Cannot GET /addUser`

```
<a class="nav-link" href="../pages/addUser">New member</a>
```

It's not only that specific page that I'm unable to access, it's any other page that I refer to outside of the  `"/"`

I have added an image that shows the file structure, if it's any help

[image]

Comment: `href="/addUser"`

Comment: I already tried that konrad, the result is the saem

Comment: Show where you import `memberRoutes.js` and how you use it

Comment: Actually you're right @Konrad, I see now that that was the issue.  In the app.js I needed to add  app.use('/addUser', userRoute)  instead of     app.use('/', userRoute). This is my first node.js application and working with routes.  If you make it so that I can mark your comment/help as a solution, I'll do that